# mp3 stream decoding in browser

Tags: javascript, c++, c, mp3, emscripten

I am trying to set up an mp3 stream receiver in browser using emscripten and libmad.
I managed to decode mp3 file with low-level api loading it completely to the memory. My next step was to load it in chunks.
In [given example](https://macaw.me/jsmad) I emulate fragmented packages with allocated buffers of random size (from 20 to 40 kbyte) and copy file part by part to those buffers.

My algorithm of decoding correlate with an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803572/libmad-playback-too-fast-if-read-in-chunks) but it is a bit different. The main object is Decoder, it receives fragments by addFragment method. Decoder has a pull of pending fragments and a glue buffer. When user adds first fragment its tail is copied in the first half of the glue buffer. When the second fragment is added it's beginning being copied to the second half of the glue. When decoder reaches the end of active buffer end it switches to glue, and vice versa when glue finishes. I make sure all those buffers parts are consistent and mad_stream points to the same logical byte it was pointing before switching.

**Significant fragments from decoder.cpp**

```
void Decoder::addFragment          //adds the fragment to decoding queue
(intptr_t bufferPtr, uint32_t length)
{
    if (length < GLUE_LENGTH / 2) {
        return;
    }
    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t(*))bufferPtr;
    RawBuffer rb = {buffer, length};
    pending.push_back(rb);

    switch (state) {
        case empty:
            mad_stream_buffer(&stream, buffer, length);

            for (int i = 0; i < GLUE_LENGTH/2; ++i) {
                glue[i] = buffer[length - GLUE_LENGTH/2 + i];
            }

            state = onBufferHalf;
            prepareNextBuffer();
            break;
        case onBufferHalf:
            for (int i = 0; i < GLUE_LENGTH/2; ++i) {
                glue[GLUE_LENGTH/2 + i] = buffer[i];
            }

            state = onBufferFull;
            break;
        case onGlueHalf:
            for (int i = 0; i < GLUE_LENGTH/2; ++i) {
                glue[GLUE_LENGTH/2 + i] = buffer[i];
            }

            state = onGlueFull;
            cached = false;
            prepareNextBuffer();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

emscripten::val Decoder::decode     //decodes up to requested amount of frames
(uint32_t count)
{
    emscripten::val ret = emscripten::val::undefined();

    int available = framesLeft(count);
    if (available > 0) {
        ret = context.call<emscripten::val>("createBuffer", channels, available * samplesPerFrame, sampleRate);

        std::vector<emscripten::val> chans(channels, emscripten::val::undefined());
        for (int i = 0; i < channels; ++i) {
            chans[i] = ret.call<emscripten::val>("getChannelData", i);
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < available; ++i) {
            int res = mad_frame_decode(&frame, &stream);

            if (res != 0) {
                if (MAD_RECOVERABLE(stream.error)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            mad_synth_frame(&synth, &frame);
            for (int j = 0; j < samplesPerFrame; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < channels; ++k) {
                    float value = mad_f_todouble(synth.pcm.samples[k][j]);
                    chans[k].set(std::to_string(success * samplesPerFrame + j), emscripten::val(value));
                }
            }
        }

        cachedLength -= available;
        if (cachedLength == 0) {
            cached = false;
            prepareNextBuffer();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


//tells how many frames can be decoded on the same
//sample rate, same amount of channels without switching the buffers
//it is required in Decoder::decode method to understand the size of 
//allocating AudioContext::AudioBuffer.

uint32_t Decoder::framesLeft(uint32_t max)
{
    if (state == empty || state == onGlueHalf) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (cached == false) {
        mad_stream probe;
        mad_header ph;
        initializeProbe(probe);
        mad_header_init(&ph);

        while (cachedLength < max) {
            if (mad_header_decode(&ph, &probe) == 0) {
                if (sampleRate == 0) {
                    sampleRate = ph.samplerate;
                    channels = MAD_NCHANNELS(&ph);
                    samplesPerFrame = MAD_NSBSAMPLES(&ph) * 32;
                } else {
                    if (sampleRate != ph.samplerate || channels != MAD_NCHANNELS(&ph) || samplesPerFrame != MAD_NSBSAMPLES(&ph) * 32) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (probe.next_frame > probe.this_frame) {
                    ++cachedLength;
                }
            } else {
                if (!MAD_RECOVERABLE(probe.error)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        cachedNext = probe.next_frame;
        cachedThis = probe.this_frame;
        cachedError = probe.error;
        mad_header_finish(&ph);
        mad_stream_finish(&probe);
        cached = true;
    }

    return std::min(cachedLength, max);
}

//this method fastforwards the stream
//to the cached end
void Decoder::pullBuffer()
{
    if (cached == false) {
        throw 2;
    }
    stream.this_frame = cachedThis;
    stream.next_frame = cachedNext;
    stream.error = cachedError;
}

//this method switches the stream to glue buffer
//or to the next pending buffer
//copies the parts to the glue buffer if required

void Decoder::changeBuffer()
{
    uint32_t left;
    switch (state) {
        case empty:
            throw 3;
        case onBufferHalf:
            switchToGlue();
            state = onGlueHalf;
            break;
        case onBufferFull:
            switchToGlue();
            state = onGlueFull;
            break;
        case onGlueHalf:
            throw 4;
            break;
        case onGlueFull:
            switchBuffer(pending[0].ptr, pending[0].length);

            for (int i = 0; i < GLUE_LENGTH/2; ++i) {
                glue[i] = pending[0].ptr[pending[0].length - GLUE_LENGTH/2 + i];
            }
            state = onBufferHalf;

            if (pending.size() > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < GLUE_LENGTH/2; ++i) {
                    glue[GLUE_LENGTH/2 + i] = pending[1].ptr[i];
                }
                state = onBufferFull;
            }
    }

    cached = false;
}

//this method seeks the decodable data in pending buffers
//prepares if any proper data has been found
void Decoder::prepareNextBuffer()
{
    bool shift;
    do {
        shift = false;
        framesLeft();
        if (cachedLength == 0 && state != empty && state != onGlueHalf) {
            pullBuffer();
            changeBuffer();
            shift = true;
        }
    } while (shift);
}

//low level method to switch to glue buffer, also frees the drained fragment
void Decoder::switchToGlue()
{
    switchBuffer(glue, GLUE_LENGTH);
    stream.error = MAD_ERROR_NONE;

    free(pending[0].ptr);
    pending.pop_front();
}

//low level method which actually switch mad_stream
//to another buffer
void Decoder::switchBuffer(uint8_t* bufferPtr, uint32_t length)
{
    uint32_t left;
    left = stream.bufend - stream.next_frame;
    mad_stream_buffer(&stream, bufferPtr + GLUE_LENGTH / 2 - left, length - (GLUE_LENGTH / 2 - left));
    stream.error = MAD_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

[Here](https://git.macaw.me/blue/jsmad) is my repo with full code. To try it you need to build it with CMake (emscripten is supposed to be installed) and open index.html from the build directory in your browser.

**The problem**
The playback is distorted. I tried to check the bytes around last successful frame before and after shift, all of the different substructures of mad_stream - everything seems to work properly but it still doesn't. My latest progress is built and hosted [here](https://macaw.me/jsmad).
I'am really stuck and I don't know what to do to eliminate distortion in the playback.

I would really appreciate if someone helps me.

Comment: And the specific question is?

Comment: The specific question is how to make libmad decode the stream of chunks without those gaps in playback. Or, may be, how else do it using other tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it! MAD works perfectly, just because of my inner counter I kept skipping first decoded frames in output.

```
for (int i = 0; success < available; ++i) {
            int res = mad_frame_decode(frame, stream);

            if (res == 0) {
                ++**success**;
            } else {
                if (MAD_RECOVERABLE(stream->error)) {

                    std::cout << "Unexpected error during the decoding process: " << mad_stream_errorstr(stream) << std::endl;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            mad_synth_frame(synth, frame);

            for (int j = 0; j < samplesPerFrame; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < channels; ++k) {
                    float value = mad_f_todouble(synth->pcm.samples[k][j]);
                    chans[k].set(std::to_string(success * samplesPerFrame + j), emscripten::val(value));
                }
            }
        }
```

changed **success** to **i** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different answers here, but one solution is through [socket.io](https://socket.io/). Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627210/how-to-stream-data-over-socket-io-to-client/48627791#48627791) of someone setting up streaming binary to a client. This would avoid doing the segmentation on the server and entrust the client to do it for you.

The missing piece here is running the binary through an mp3 decoder. Some libraries can automatically determine the format but you might have to also pass the encoding type so it knows how to parse the binary stream. It might be that's already offered in aurora but I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: But I do run it through the mp3 decoder - it's libmad, and it decodes. The issue is that it is probably not used correctly, there are gaps on the edges of fragments during the playback. The question is mostly about what am I doing wrong using libmad.

Comment: I'd take a look here then. It sounds fairly similar to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803572/libmad-playback-too-fast-if-read-in-chunks?noredirect=1&lq=1. Glancing through it the answer seems to be to increase the frame size.

Comment: I've seen that, even have a reference to that answer in the question, it helps to understand libmad better, but doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.