# How do I tell libmad which file to decode?

Tags: mp3, decoding

I have seen a few examples of **libmad** usage and I can't locate in the code where the programmer tells libmad which file to decode, I expect to be some sort of function and the file name being one of its parameters.

It would be nice if you could provide some exapmle code

I am using Windows

---

Any answer with good intentions is appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/8106yogi/waveloop/tree/master/WaveLoop

Comment: @noname what is this? some other decoder?

Comment: It is an android application using libmad library