# Delphi VCL TMediaPlayer: file path/name length limit

Tags: delphi, filepath, vcl, maxlength, tmediaplayer

Using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition, VCL, Windows 10 64bit, although the compiled `.exe` application is 32bit.

The VCL's `TMediaPlayer` seems to have a file path/name length limit of 128 characters. Is this really an internal limitation? Is there any way to access longer file paths/names?

I was coding a small soundPad player by using the `TMediaPlayer` component.

The installer I am using installs the `.exe` program in the user's home directory, and at the same time a few sample audio files in the program's root directory.

In this case, the path to the audio file may be quite long. For example:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MySoundPlayer\ThisIsMySoundWithAVeryLongFileNameThereIsSomeCopyrightInfoAndSomeOther.wav

When trying to play such a file, `TMediaPlayer` will give an error message:

```
Exception class name = 'EMCIDeviceError'
Exception message = 'Invalid filename. Make sure the filename has 8 characters, a period, and an extension.'
```

I tried different lengths in the file name, and it looks like 127 is the maximum length.

So, the VCL `TMediaPlayer` component does not recognize file paths / names longer than 127 characters?

I tried the same code with a Delphi FMX app, and FMX's `TMediaPlayer` worked ok. It seems that the maximum file path and name length of the FMX `TMediaPlayer` is 259, which is quite sufficient.

The length 259 seem to be the limit of the File Explorer overall...

It is said that the VCL's `TMediaPlayer` component is starting to become obsolete, and is only involved in backward compatibility reasons. But what can replace it in the future?

So, I guess I have to move on to FMX and learn its secrets. Is VCL a receding component system?

```
procedure TForm1.PlayButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  pathstring, playerfilename, playstring : string;
begin
  try
    pathstring := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
    playerfilename := 'ThisIsMySoundWithAVeryLongFileNameThereIsSomeCopyrightInfoAndSomeOther.wav';
    playstring := pathstring + playerfilename;
    MediaPlayer1.FileName := playstring;
    MediaPlayer1.Open;
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Exception class name = ' + E.ClassName);
      ShowMessage('Exception message = ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you using the Media Player in VCL or FMX?

Comment: I'm using it in VCL.

Comment: Please edit your question to include complete path that you attempt to use, OS version, code and error message.

Comment: The error message is **only** about the filename being at max 8.3 in length (f.e. `12345678.wav` at max) - please try changing the filename. Yes, most software in Windows cannot handle [path+filenames longer than 260 characters - that's a well-known limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).

Answer (score 2):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393513/65863) to [`mciSendString()` won't play an audio file if path is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221390/):

> Here, `mmioOpen` is called with `MMIO_PARSE` flag to convert file path to fully qualified file path. According to MSDN, this has a limitation:
>
> > The buffer must be large enough to hold at least 128 characters.
>
> That is, buffer is always assumed to be 128 bytes long. For long filenames, the buffer turns out to be insufficient and `mmioOpen` returns error, causing `mciSendCommand` to think that sound file is missing and return `MCIERR_FILENAME_REQUIRED`.

The `Invalid filename` error message you are seeing is the system text for the `MCIERR_FILENAME_REQUIRED` error code.

The VCL's `TMediaPlayer` is based on MCI and internally uses `mciSendCommand()`, which is just the binary version of `mciSendString()`. They both suffer from the same problem.

The preferred fix is to either use shorter paths, or use a more modern audio API.

However, since [`mmioInstallIOProc()` can be used to let `TMediaPlayer` play media files from memory instead of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72326129/65863), I think a similar solution could be used to play files with long file paths, since you could take over the responsibility of opening/reading/seeking a file, bypassing the path limitation of the troublesome `mmioOpen()`. Just replace the `TResourceStream` in that code with a `TFileStream`, and update the `MMIOM_READ` and `MMIOM_SEEK` handlers accordingly to read/seek that `TFileStream`.

For example (untested, might need some tweaking):

```pascal
uses
  Winapi.MMSystem;

var
  ccRES: FOURCC;
  playstring: string;

function MAKEFOURCC(ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3: BYTE): FOURCC;
begin
  Result := DWORD(ch0) or (DWORD(ch1) shl 8) or (DWORD(ch2) shl 16) or (DWORD(ch3) shl 24); 
end;

function MyLongFileIOProc(lpMMIOInfo: PMMIOInfo; uMessage: UINT; lParam1, lParam2: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  FStrm: TFileStream;
  NumRead: Integer;

  function GetFileStream: TFileStream;
  begin
    Move(lpMMIOInfo.adwInfo, Result, SizeOf(TFileStream));
  end;

  procedure SetFileStream(Stream: TFileStream);
  begin
    Move(Stream, lpMMIOInfo.adwInfo, SizeOf(TFileStream));
  end;

begin
  if uMessage = MMIOM_OPEN then
  begin
    try
      FStrm := TFileStream.Create(playstring, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    except
      SetFileStream(nil);
      Exit(MMIOM_CANNOTOPEN);
    end;
    SetFileStream(FStrm);
    lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := 0;
  end else
  begin
    FStrm := GetFileStream;
    case uMessage of
      MMIOM_CLOSE: begin
        SetFileStream(nil);
        FStrm.Free;
      end;   
      MMIOM_READ: begin
        NumRead := FStrm.Read(Pointer(lParam1)^, lParam2);
        Inc(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset, NumRead);
        Exit(NumRead);
      end;
      MMIOM_SEEK: begin
        FStrm.Seek(Int64(lParam1), TSeekOrigin(lParam2));
        lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := FStrm.Position;
        Exit(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset);
      end;
  end;
  Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ccRES := MAKEFOURCC(Ord('L'), Ord('F'), Ord('N'), Ord(' '));
  mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, TFNMMIOProc(MyLongFileIOProc), MMIO_INSTALLPROC); 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, nil, MMIO_REMOVEPROC);
end;

procedure TForm1.PlayButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  pathstring, playerfilename : string;
begin
  try
    pathstring := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
    playerfilename := 'ThisIsMySoundWithAVeryLongFileNameThereIsSomeCopyrightInfoAndSomeOther.wav';
    playstring := pathstring + playerfilename;

    MediaPlayer1.DeviceType := dtWaveAudio;
    MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'playstring.LFN+';
    MediaPlayer1.Open;
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Exception class name = ' + E.ClassName);
      ShowMessage('Exception message = ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```