# How can I play mp3 files in Windows 11 using cmd?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, windows-11

I made an app recently that I'm proud of. It's an alarm that plays music at a designated time. I use the Windows Command Prompt to play the .mp3 file. I'm using C, so I've been trying to use the `system()` method. However, I've realized that this won't work on computers that have Windows 11, as they got rid of Windows Media Player being installed with Win11. I also have Win11, but it worked on my computer because I installed it.

Win11's media player is called "Media Player," and I can't find a way to play mp3 files through the command line with it. I've tried "fmedia," "wmplayer," "start," and others but none of them work.

So how can I play an mp3 file on Windows 11 using the Command Prompt without installing extra software?

Comment: *So how can I play an mp3 file on Windows 11 using the Command Prompt without installing extra software?* - why are you sure it is even possible? Sure there are command line players out there, but you do need to install them.

Comment: So then how can someone play an mp3 file in C without installing extra software other than C packages?

Comment: They write an actual MP3 player in C. And yes, among the "C packages" might be a library that helps writing such a player.

Comment: Why do you want to use the command line? Windows has `PlaySound(filename, NULL, SND_FILENAME)`.

Comment: @MSalters Are you sure it works with anything other than `wav`? Upd: To an extent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049825/simplest-way-to-play-mp3-from-visual-c

Comment: FWIW, you can enable Windows Media Player via the *Windows Features*. That said, you should probably just use the legacy Win32 API ``PlaySound`` instead of relying on a specific app and it would be most portable if you didn't rely on a 3rd party media format like `MP3`. Just use a `WAV` with PCM data. Media Foundation is *not* present on "N" editions of Windows (i.e. Europe) by default. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/who-moved-my-windows-media-cheese/).

Comment: Have a look at [mpg123 audio player](http://mpg123.org), which can be called from a console program. Not tried on Windows 11, though there was a 2022 release.

Comment: I would advise that you do not ever force your preferred software on any user. If they have chosen a particular software for .mp3 files and/or do not want the abysmal Windows Media Player to run, then you should not override their preference. It's their computer, not yours!

Comment: You can always write your own mp3 player, it would be a good coding exercise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play audio file on windows from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569765/how-to-play-audio-file-on-windows-from-command-line)